# How to remove redundant spaces in the .tex file using latexindent?

Tags: formatting, latexindent

Example:

```
\begin{align}
  a + b = c
\end{align}
[more spaces here] <=
```

I am using the latexindent to format my tex file. However, each time I format the file, it will create more space after some blocks, like the align. Shown as above.

How to remove those redundant spaces?

I set my default indentation to be "  " (two spaces).

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, it's kind of answering my own question:

change the

```
removeTrailingWhitespace: 0
```

to be

```
removeTrailingWhitespace: 1
```

in the `defaultSettings.yaml`

Done.

Comment: Glad you found the answer :) for reference: https://latexindentpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sec-default-user-local.html?highlight=Removetrailingwhitespace#yaml-removetrailingwhitespace